# MySQL bigint display issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have an id column in MySQL database specified as:
`` Scan_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL ``

I am seeing some strange behavior when querying. The last digits of ids are displayed changed in editor. But
when I am retrieving the values programmatically from python I get the correct ones. Same if I cast the number as character.

So this query `SELECT CAST(Scan_id AS CHAR), Scan_id FROM Table_Name;` has the below result in editor:
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeWP0.png)

Left are the actual values and right is (for some reason) integers displayed changed.

I have noticed this behavior only in numbers above 16 digits. I guess since I am able to get correct values this is not a storage issue, but a display one. But I really don't understand where is it coming from. Can someone please explain to me?

Comment: an unsigned bigint can store values up to 2**64-1.  it sounds like your python code is storing it in a floating point type that is only providing 56 bits of precision, either at the point you read it from mysql or at some later point before displaying it.  I'm not familiar with python mysql libraries or if there is a way to tell it to store your return value in a python int/long type; it would likely help someone help you if you showed your python code

Comment: There is no issue on python side. It is sent as integer only and also when I am retrieving the values from database in python I get the correct values. So it is not a storage issue either. From any search I have done I am only assuming that it is a display issue in the SQL editor UI, that is why they are shown like this. So maybe I can just ignore it

Comment: oh, this is just your sql editor, not your python code?  for future readers of this question, please make clear what your "query result" is from